# Rails: uninitialized constant Model::RenamedAssociation when using class to specify model in relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have 3 tables, Charges, Transactions and Charges_Transactions.

I had to rename the associations on my models as there is an existing transactions method which was interfering with the association. See [this article](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/59-fixing-the-you-tried-to-define-an-association-named-transaction-ruby-on-rails-error)

```
class Charge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :payment_transactions, join_table: "charges_transactions", foreign_key: "charge_id",
      association_foreign_key: "transaction_id", class: 'Transaction'
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :charges, join_table: "charges_transactions", foreign_key: "transaction_id",
      association_foreign_key: "charge_id"
end

@charge.payment_transactions
```

Now when I try to access the associated transactions for any charge I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant Charge::PaymentTransaction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing: 
`class: 'Transaction'`
To:
`class_name: 'Transaction'`

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

> If the name of the other model cannot be derived from the association
>   name, you can use the :class_name option to supply the model name. For
>   example, if an order belongs to a customer, but the actual name of the
>   model containing customers is Patron, you'd set things up this way:
>
> class Order < ActiveRecord::Base   belongs_to :customer, class_name:
>   "Patron" end